# How do I configure winrm ssl/tls to lo listen on 5896 with a GPO

Tags: windows, winrm

I have a piece of monitoring software with which I want to start monitoring securely. My goals are:

- Use TLS for transport encryption and not rely on message encryption
- Use a certrificate authority
- I want to avoid running some powershell script on every machine before I can start monitoring. I want to use GPO's or something similar (I'm no sysadmin) that does the changes globally.
- I don't want to use the Compatibility server because IIS or some other webserver might already be present on the monitored host.
- It should preferably work on any server version > 2008

Following [this tutorial](https://www.darkoperator.com/blog/2015/3/24/bdvjiiw1ybzfdjulc5pprgpkm8os0b) we (read, my colleague) came this far

```
C:\Windows\system32>winrm e winrm/config/listener
Listener [Source="GPO"]
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTP
    Port = 5985
    Hostname
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint
    ListeningOn = 127.0.0.1, 1.2.3.4
```

However at the end we have to run this CMD command to enable HTTPS on 5986

```
winrm create winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS
@{Hostname="<HOSTNAME HERE>"; CertificateThumbprint="<THUMBPRINT HERE>"}
```

I can't be the only one who has these goals? I can't believe that doing it in a way that feels correct (to me) is just impossible.

We've also found [this workaround](https://dscottraynsford.wordpress.com/2015/09/27/install-an-ssl-ws-management-listener-with-gpo/) but would prefer a more straight-forward solution.